# Multiple Powershell processes maxing out cpu usage

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu-usage, throttling

For some reason powershell runs its own processes without my permission.

It happens randomly and it re-launches processes of itself even after I have ended them. Sometime when I end those processes, they pop up within a few minutes or hours.

Each powershell process that runs on its own usually takes up about 25% CPU.

Any Ideas? I am running windows 10 Enterprise on a HP elite book.

Comment: Company laptop or personal? If it's a company machine then those are likely scripts being run by a GPO or scheduled task.

Comment: Yeah, it is a company laptop.